# there has been an error , unable to write inside TEMP environment variable path

Tags: postgresql, temp

while i install postgresql ,there has been an error there has been an error , "unable to write inside TEMP environment variable path"

I looked at bitrock_installer.log and it shows:

> Log started 10/16/2018 at 15:39:49 Preferred installation mode : qt
>   Trying to init installer in mode qt Mode qt successfully initialized
>   Executing cscript //NoLogo
>   "C:\Users\Propc\AppData\Local\Temp\postgresql_installer_e1e7f98092\prerun_checks.vbs"
>   Script exit code: 1
>
> Script output:  Input Error: There is no script engine for file
>   extension ".vbs".
>
> Script stderr:  Program ended with an error exit code
>
> Error running cscript //NoLogo
>   "C:\Users\Propc\AppData\Local\Temp\postgresql_installer_e1e7f98092\prerun_checks.vbs":
>   Program ended with an error exit code

Comment: What PostgreSQL installer are you using? What is the environment variable `TEMP` set to?

Comment: i install postgresql on windows .exe,

Comment: C:\Users\Propc\AppData\Local\Temp

Comment: Try with EnterpriseDB's binaries. They usually work for me.